# Disable Jenkins simultaneous builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wish to disable some simultaneous build in Jenkins and if one is running the second added to queue and only starts when the first is finished (just preventing it from running it also OK).
I installed this plugin: [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) but just can`t get around how to work with it. What is "Per Node"? And if I adding category in settings why cant I see it in projects. 
What I need is create some Category and prevent build that in this category to run simultaneously. Can some one please help me to understand how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

Regardig [Mobrockers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1890387/mobrockers) answer:
[image]

1. Create a category, in the project configuration for both projects.

Where is the category creation?

3. Set Multi-Project Throttle Category to the category you created.

I don`t see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a category, in the project configuration for both projects

Set the option Throttle concurrent builds to true

Set Multi-Project Throttle Category to the category you created

Enable Throttle this project as part of one or more categories

Set Maximum Total Concurrent Builds to 1

Set Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node to 1

Comment: There is a category right there called Android Concurrent Builds. If you want more categories, you never create things such as this in the project configuration. These settings are found in the global jenkins configuration (as they span more than just this project).